# Datetime Invalid Comparison Error with PYTZ

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime, pytz

I keep getting the following error when trying to filter my dataframe on datetime objects: `TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(120)] and DatetimeArray`. This is the first time I encounter this error, while I have had to use this kind of filtering before.

This is my code (including the steps to convertthe datetime objects):

```
# Create a date column for merging and set date formats
df_fpu["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df_fpu["datetime"])
df_fpu["date"] = df_fpu["datetime"].dt.date
df_fpu["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_fpu["date"])

# Set to the correct time zone
df_fpu.datetime.astype('datetime64[ns]')
df_fpu.date.astype('datetime64[ns]')

# Also make sure to have the correct time format in df_events (already in correct tz)
df_events["start_datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df_events["start_datetime"])
df_events["end_datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df_events["end_datetime"])
df_events["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_events["date"])

# Merge df_fpu on df_events
df_merged = pd.merge(df_events, df_fpu, on=["stand", "date"], how="inner")

# We want to filter this dataframe on the start and end times of each flights to remove incorrect records
df_fpu = df_merged[(df_merged["datetime"] >= df_merged["start_datetime"]) & (df_merged["datetime"] <= df_merged["end_datetime"])]
```

Does anyone know why this error occurs? I got 10 rows of sample data:

| start_datetime | end_datetime | stand | date | datetime | num_signals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-28T20:53:14.000+0000 | 2022-04-28T22:27:02.000+0000 | G06 | 2022-04-28T00:00:00.000+0000 | 2022-04-28T05:33:00.000+0000 | 5 |
| 2022-04-28T20:53:14.000+0000 | 2022-04-28T22:27:02.000+0000 | G06 | 2022-04-28T00:00:00.000+0000 | 2022-04-28T05:34:00.000+0000 | 8 |
| 2022-04-28T20:53:14.000+0000 | 2022-04-28T22:27:02.000+0000 | G06 | 2022-04-28T00:00:00.000+0000 | 2022-04-28T05:35:00.000+0000 | 10 |
| 2022-04-28T20:53:14.000+0000 | 2022-04-28T22:27:02.000+0000 | G06 | 2022-04-28T00:00:00.000+0000 | 2022-04-28T05:36:00.000+0000 | 17 |
| 2022-04-28T20:53:14.000+0000 | 2022-04-28T22:27:02.000+0000 | G06 | 2022-04-28T00:00:00.000+0000 | 2022-04-28T05:37:00.000+0000 | 19 |
| 2022-04-28T20:53:14.000+0000 | 2022-04-28T22:27:02.000+0000 | G06 | 2022-04-28T00:00:00.000+0000 | 2022-04-28T05:38:00.000+0000 | 30 |
| 2022-04-28T20:53:14.000+0000 | 2022-04-28T22:27:02.000+0000 | G06 | 2022-04-28T00:00:00.000+0000 | 2022-04-28T05:39:00.000+0000 | 23 |
| 2022-04-28T20:53:14.000+0000 | 2022-04-28T22:27:02.000+0000 | G06 | 2022-04-28T00:00:00.000+0000 | 2022-04-28T05:40:00.000+0000 | 23 |
| 2022-04-28T20:53:14.000+0000 | 2022-04-28T22:27:02.000+0000 | G06 | 2022-04-28T00:00:00.000+0000 | 2022-04-28T05:41:00.000+0000 | 24 |
| 2022-04-28T20:53:14.000+0000 | 2022-04-28T22:27:02.000+0000 | G06 | 2022-04-28T00:00:00.000+0000 | 2022-04-28T05:42:00.000+0000 | 24 |

Comment: Your data most likely has mixed UTC offsets. Try using `pd.to_datetime([...], utc=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

please check the shape of the datetime objects:

```
print(df_merged["datetime"].shape)
print(df_merged["start_datetime"].shape)
print(df_merged["end_datetime"].shape)
```

If the data types and timezones are consistent, it's possible that the shape of the datetime objects is causing the error. Make sure that the datetime, start_datetime, and end_datetime columns have the same shape by checking their shape attribute.
If they don't (and it could not be visible in the first 10 rows) , you may need to reshape one or more of the columns before performing the comparison.
For the sample You have provided  It looks like your code is working (assuming that this table corresponds to the df_merged)